# Rubiks cube in golang using ebiten

Tags: go

In my project for linear algebra, I'm trying to make a 2x2 rubik's cube. I've worked out alot of the logic but i keep running into a runtime error.
The code for the cube is:

```
package game

import (
    "math"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2"
)

const DeltaTheta = 1. / 360 * (2 * math.Pi)
const ScreenSize = 1000
const Pad = 250
const a = 8
const b = a * 5
const c = a * 6
const d = a * 7

var Connect = [96][2]int{{1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}, {5, 7}, {7, 6}, //cube 1
    {0 + 8, 2 + 8}, {0 + 8, 3 + 8}, {2 + 8, 4 + 8}, {2 + 8, 6 + 8}, {3 + 8, 4 + 8}, {3 + 8, 5 + 8}, {4 + 8, 7 + 8}, {5 + 8, 7 + 8}, {7 + 8, 6 + 8}, //cube 2
    {0 + 2*a, 1 + 2*a}, {0 + 2*a, 3 + 2*a}, {1 + 2*a, 5 + 2*a}, {1 + 2*a, 6 + 2*a}, {3 + 2*a, 4 + 2*a}, {3 + 2*a, 5 + 2*a}, {4 + 2*a, 7 + 2*a}, {5 + 2*a, 7 + 2*a}, {7 + 2*a, 6 + 2*a}, //cube 3
    {0 + 3*a, 1 + 3*a}, {0 + 3*a, 2 + 3*a}, {1 + 3*a, 5 + 3*a}, {1 + 3*a, 6 + 3*a}, {2 + 3*a, 4 + 3*a}, {2 + 3*a, 6 + 3*a}, {4 + 3*a, 7 + 3*a}, {5 + 3*a, 7 + 3*a}, {7 + 3*a, 6 + 3*a}, //cube 4
    {0 + 4*a, 1 + 4*a}, {0 + 4*a, 2 + 4*a}, {0 + 4*a, 3 + 4*a}, {1 + 4*a, 5 + 4*a}, {2 + 4*a, 4 + 4*a}, {3 + 4*a, 4 + 4*a}, {3 + 4*a, 5 + 4*a}, {4 + 4*a, 7 + 4*a}, {5 + 4*a, 7 + 4*a}, //cube 5
    {0 + b, 1 + b}, {0 + b, 2 + b}, {0 + b, 3 + b}, {1 + b, 5 + b}, {1 + b, 6 + b}, {2 + b, 6 + b}, {3 + b, 5 + b}, {5 + b, 7 + b}, {7 + b, 6 + b}, //cube 6
    {0 + c, 1 + c}, {0 + c, 2 + c}, {0 + c, 3 + c}, {1 + c, 6 + c}, {2 + c, 4 + c}, {2 + c, 6 + c}, {3 + c, 4 + c}, {4 + c, 7 + c}, {7 + c, 6 + c}, //cube 7
    {0 + d, 1 + d}, {0 + d, 2 + d}, {0 + d, 3 + d}, {1 + d, 5 + d}, {1 + d, 6 + d}, {2 + d, 4 + d}, {2 + d, 6 + d}, {3 + d, 4 + d}, {3 + d, 5 + d}, //cube 8
}

type Cube struct {
    Vertices [64]Vector
    Colors   [96]int
}

func NewGame() *Cube {
    return &Cube{
        Vertices: [64]Vector{
            {0, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 1},
            //cube 1
            {0 - 1, 0, 0},
            {1 - 1, 0, 0},
            {0 - 1, 1, 0},
            {0 - 1, 0, 1},
            {0 - 1, 1, 1},
            {1 - 1, 0, 1},
            {1 - 1, 1, 0},
            {1 - 1, 1, 1},
            //cube 2
            {0, 0 - 1, 0},
            {1, 0 - 1, 0},
            {0, 1 - 1, 0},
            {0, 0 - 1, 1},
            {0, 1 - 1, 1},
            {1, 0 - 1, 1},
            {1, 1 - 1, 0},
            {1, 1 - 1, 1},
            //cube3
            {0, 0, 0 - 1},
            {1, 0, 0 - 1},
            {0, 1, 0 - 1},
            {0, 0, 1 - 1},
            {0, 1, 1 - 1},
            {1, 0, 1 - 1},
            {1, 1, 0 - 1},
            {1, 1, 1 - 1},
            //cube4
            {0 - 1, 0 - 1, 0},
            {1 - 1, 0 - 1, 0},
            {0 - 1, 1 - 1, 0},
            {0 - 1, 0 - 1, 1},
            {0 - 1, 1 - 1, 1},
            {1 - 1, 0 - 1, 1},
            {1 - 1, 1 - 1, 0},
            {1 - 1, 1 - 1, 1},
            //cube5
            {0, 0 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {1, 0 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {0, 1 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {0, 0 - 1, 1 - 1},
            {0, 1 - 1, 1 - 1},
            {1, 0 - 1, 1 - 1},
            {1, 1 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {1, 1 - 1, 1 - 1},
            //cube6
            {0 - 1, 0, 0 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 0, 0 - 1},
            {0 - 1, 1, 0 - 1},
            {0 - 1, 0, 1 - 1},
            {0 - 1, 1, 1 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 0, 1 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 1, 0 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 1, 1 - 1},
            //cube7
            {0 - 1, 0 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 0 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {0 - 1, 1 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {0 - 1, 0 - 1, 1 - 1},
            {0 - 1, 1 - 1, 1 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 0 - 1, 1 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 1 - 1, 0 - 1},
            {1 - 1, 1 - 1, 1 - 1},
            //cube8
        },
        Colors: [96]int{
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, // Assign color indices to vertices
            8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, // ... (repeat for the rest of the vertices)
            16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
            24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
            32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
            40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
            48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
            56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63,
        },
        
    }
}

func (g *Cube) Update() error {
    keyPressed := false
    var m Matrix
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyArrowRight) {
        m = YaxisRotate(DeltaTheta)
        keyPressed = true
    }
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyArrowLeft) {
        m = YaxisRotate(-DeltaTheta)
        keyPressed = true
    }
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyArrowUp) {
        m = LatitudeRotate(DeltaTheta)
        keyPressed = true
    }
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyArrowDown) {
        m = LatitudeRotate(-DeltaTheta)
        keyPressed = true
    }
    if keyPressed {
        for i, v := range g.Vertices {
            g.Vertices[i] = m.MulVec(v)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (g *Cube) Draw(screen *ebiten.Image) {
    for i := 0; i < len(Connect); i++ {
        colorIndex := g.Colors[i]
        color := CubeColors[colorIndex]

        var xy [2][2]int
        for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
            for k := 0; k < 2; k++ {
                xy[j][k] = Pad + int((g.Vertices[Connect[i][j]][k]+1)/2*(ScreenSize-2*Pad))
            }
        }

        stepX := Max(xy[1][0]-xy[0][0], 0)
        stepY := Max(xy[1][1]-xy[0][1], 0)

        for k := 0; k <= Max(stepX, stepY); k++ {
            for dx := -2 / 2; dx <= 2/2; dx++ {
                for dy := -2 / 2; dy <= 2/2; dy++ {
                    p := [2]int{
                        xy[0][0] + int(float64(k)*float64(xy[1][0]-xy[0][0])/float64(Max(stepX, stepY))) + dx,
                        xy[0][1] + int(float64(k)*float64(xy[1][1]-xy[0][1])/float64(Max(stepX, stepY))) + dy,
                    }
                    screen.Set(p[0], p[1], color)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}





func (g *Cube) Layout(outsideWidth, outsideHeight int) (int, int) {
    return ScreenSize, ScreenSize
}

func Max(a, b int) int {
    if a < 0 {
        a = -a
    }
    if b < 0 {
        b = -b
    }
    if a < b {
        return b
    }
    return a
}
```

I have a seperate file for defining colors

```
// colors.go
package game

import (
    "image/color"
)

var CubeColors = []color.RGBA{
    {255, 0, 0, 255},    // Red
    {0, 255, 0, 255},    // Green
    {0, 0, 255, 255},    // Blue
    {255, 255, 0, 255},  // Yellow
    {255, 255, 255, 255},// White
}
```

The error i keep encountering is
`panic: runtime error: index out of range [5] with length 5`

I've tried changing the code in Draw function plenty of times but it just ends up in giving the wrong output. I still have to work out the cube rotation logic but im still stuck on the coloring step.

I'm expecting to have a colored structured of a 2x2 rubik's cube on which i can implement the cube rotation.

Comment: Which place exactly do you get error